# Retrieve specific data from string in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, string

I'm trying to retrieve an integer from string and a string subsequently

```
NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

This returns me a string that looks like this:

```
{"customer_id":0,"message":"The account is not existed."}
```

I want to retrieve the customer_id and the message in two different places

```
NSInteger *int = [requestReply objectForKey:@"customer_id"];
NSString *msg = [requestReply objectForKey:@"message"];
```

How do I retrieve the integer and message? example?

Comment: Is that a JSON response? If it is, parse the JSON to a dictionary.

Comment: BTW - what is your question? You've only stated what to want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like JSON, you can do it like this in that case:

```
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[requestReply dataWithEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
NSNumber *customerId = [json objectForKey:@"customer_id"];
NSString *msg = [json objectForKey:@"message"];
```